# Passing arguments with a selector to new .xib of a custom object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tableview that will load a new .xib when pressed. The issue is, I need to pass a custom object over to the new .xib. So far, I have:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)doTestCellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 //some other code for current view
 TestObj *testobj = [[TestObj alloc]init];

 if(shouldGo){
   cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(loadTestView:)];
   tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
 }
```

And in that method:

```
-(void)loadTestView:(TestObj *)withTestObj{

TestViewController *newView =
[[TestViewController alloc] init];
//Set the property of type TestObj
newView.testobjprop = withTestObj;

[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It throws NSInvalidArgumentException. How can I make it to where the selector will send "testobj" that was initialized in the tableview method so I can access it there?

The new .xib loads in just fine if I comment out "newView.testobjprop = withTestObj;" in the loadTestView method. So I assume the issue lies there, and it is a matter of how to pass an object from one .xib to another.

Comment: in the first place why aren't you doing this in `didSelectRow` delegate method? and when you present a `viewcontroller` with only alloc init you'll see a blank screen if you have that `viewcontroller` referenced in a `storyboard` or `xib` file, and maybe the types of the objects aren't the same so you should post more information about your issue here because there can be many thing going wrong.

Comment: @soryngod If I comment out "newView.testobjprop = withTestObj" in the loadTestView method the new .xib loads up just fine, which is why I didn't mention much else. The question really boils down to, "How do I pass an object from one .xib to another .xib?"

Comment: so the `textobjprop` is the same type as `withTestObj` ?

Comment: Yes sir. In the TesViewController.h there is a property of type TestObj *testobjprop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument from `-(void)loadTestView:(TestObj *)withTestObj` is `UIGestureRecognizer` type so that's why you get `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

If you change it to `-(void)loadTestView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)withTestObj` it will be the normal behavior.

That's why you need to use `didSelectRow:AtIndexPath` so you can pass the correct value to the `viewcontroller`.

Here you aren't using `TestObj *testobj = [[TestObj alloc]init];` at all.